# Angular Reactive forms sending data from fb group as one data

Tags: angular, typescript

i have fb group in my reactive forms and i want to send post request as one value when selected.

> "SmsSendHoursRange": "11:00-16:00",

like this.

**component.html**

```
  <form [formGroup]="newCampaignForm" class="is-half" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(newCampaignForm)">
          <div class="columns mt-3" formGroupName="SmsSendHoursRange">
                <select formControlName="start">
                  <option selected="selected">11:00</option>
                  <option>16:00</option>
                </select>
                <select formControlName="end">
                  <option selected="selected">16:00</option>
                  <option>22:00</option>
                </select>
          </div>
    </form>
```

**component.ts**

```
       this.newCampaignForm = this.fb.group({
          Name: ['',  [Validators.required]],
          SmsSendHoursRange: this.fb.group({
            start: ['',  [Validators.required]],
            end: ['',  [Validators.required]],
          }),
          Branch: ['',  [Validators.required]],
          InspectionResult: ['',  [Validators.required]],
    
    
        });
  onSubmit(form:any) {
    this.campaignService.sendCampaign(form.value).subscribe(
      (res:any)=>{
          this.router.navigateByUrl('/success');
      },
      err => {
        console.log(err);

      }
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: Did you work this out..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:

```
onSubmit(form: FormGroup) {
    let SmsSendHoursRange = form.get("SmsSendHoursRange").value;
    let value = { ...form.value };
    value.SmsSendHoursRange = `${SmsSendHoursRange.start}-${
      SmsSendHoursRange.end
    }`;
    console.log(value);
    this.campaignService.sendCampaign(value).subscribe(
      (res: any) => {
        this.router.navigateByUrl("/success");
      },
      err => {
        console.log(err);
      }
    );
  }
```

Here's the stackoverflow : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wknmha?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 1):

You can access the nested form group details as follows.

```
onSubmit(form: any) {
   const name = this.newCampaignForm.get("Name").value;
   const start = this.newCampaignForm.get("SmsSendHoursRange.start").value;
   const end = this.newCampaignForm.get("SmsSendHoursRange.end").value; 
   const postData = {'Name': name, 'SmsSendHoursRange': start +'-'+ end}

   this.campaignService.sendCampaign(postData).subscribe(
   (res:any)=>{
      this.router.navigateByUrl('/success');
   },
   err => {
      console.log(err);
  });
}
```

Stackblitz - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-forms-group-example-hbzbub